# Order by all dates below some value descending then by all dates above said value ascending

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

Given the following data:

```
Effective Date
--------------
    2014-01-01
    2015-01-01
    2016-01-01
    2017-01-01
    2018-01-01
```

I want to order by date relative to (for example) `2016-06-01`, where all descending values below `2016-06-01` come before all ascending values above `2016-06-01`.

```
Relative to date: 2016-06-01 the desired ordering is

Effective Date
--------------
    2016-01-01
    2015-01-01
    2014-01-01
    2017-01-01
    2018-01-01
```

The best way I have come up with to achieve the desired ordering is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Dates
(
    EffectiveDate DATETIME2
);

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME2 = '2016-06-01';
DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME2 = '0001-01-01';

INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2014-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2016-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2018-01-01');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Dates
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN #Dates.EffectiveDate < @CurrentDate
            THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, #Dates.EffectiveDate, @CurrentDate)
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(DAY, @CurrentDate, #Dates.EffectiveDate) - DATEDIFF(DAY, @CurrentDate, @MinDate)
    END;

DROP TABLE #Dates;
```

Is there a better way to achieve the desired ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2012 and up.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Dates
ORDER BY
    IIF(#Dates.EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate, 0,1) ASC
    , ABS(DATEDIFF(day,#Dates.EffectiveDate, @CurrentDate)) ASC;
```

If you have 2008:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Dates
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN #Dates.EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate THEN  0
        ELSE 1 END ASC
    , ABS(DATEDIFF(day,#Dates.EffectiveDate, @CurrentDate)) ASC;
```

Comment: Added the case for 2008.

Comment: Just curious... why use db specific language?  case still works in both.  is iif really that much faster?

Comment: IIF was the original answer. CASE was added after bjones comment above. I suspect they would be the same in performance, but IIF is certainly shorter.

Comment: `IIF` is merely syntactic sugar, it translates to a `CASE` expression behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit of a different approach. Let me know if this will suit your needs. I used a table variable rather than temp table.

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE
(
 EffectiveDate DATETIME2
);

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME2 = '2016-06-01';

INSERT INTO @Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2014-01-01');
INSERT INTO @Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO @Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2016-01-01');
INSERT INTO @Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO @Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2018-01-01');

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 1000000 *
    FROM @Dates t1
    WHERE EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate
    ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC 
UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 1000000 *
    FROM @Dates t2
    WHERE EffectiveDate NOT IN (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM @Dates
                            WHERE EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate
                                )
    ORDER BY EffectiveDate
) t
```

******* **Edit** *******

As mentioned by HABO, the above result set wouldn't necessarily have a guaranteed order. The below edit should take care of that.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) Sort
      FROM @Dates t1
      WHERE EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate
    UNION ALL
      SELECT *
         ,(SELECT MAX(Sort) 
            FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC) Sort
                    FROM @Dates t1
                    WHERE EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate
                  ) t2
          ) 
         + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC) Sort
    FROM @Dates t3
    WHERE EffectiveDate NOT IN (SELECT *
                                FROM @Dates
                                WHERE EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate)
) t
ORDER BY t.Sort
```

Comment: Where do you order the results? Without an `ORDER BY` clause on the final results there is no guarantee of the order. `UNION ALL` offers no guarantee to preserve order. `TOP` also does not ensure any particular order, just that the rows are a subset based on the specified `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @HABO, agreed I overlooked that. So then I got curious to see how I could make it work using the same approach. It might be ugly, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific situation the solution is straight forward; split less than current and greater than current dates in two separate columns and sort accordingly:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        EffectiveDate,
        CASE WHEN EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate THEN EffectiveDate END AS DL,
        CASE WHEN EffectiveDate >  @CurrentDate THEN EffectiveDate END AS DG
    FROM #Dates
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY DL DESC, DG
```

Result:

```
EffectiveDate       | DL                  | DG
====================+=====================+====================
2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL
2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL
2014-01-01 00:00:00 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL
2017-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL                | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
2018-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL                | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Note that it is possible to write the query without using CTEs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Dates
GO
CREATE TABLE #Dates
(
    EffectiveDate DATETIME2
);

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME2 = '2016-06-01';
DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME2 = '0001-01-01';

INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2014-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2015-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2016-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO #Dates (EffectiveDate) VALUES ('2018-01-01');

SELECT
    EffectiveDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END GroupId,
        CASE
            WHEN EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate THEN EffectiveDate
            ELSE NULL
        END Group1,
        CASE
            WHEN EffectiveDate <= @CurrentDate THEN NULL
            ELSE EffectiveDate
        END Group2,
        EffectiveDate
    FROM
        #Dates
)A
ORDER BY
    GroupId,
    Group1 DESC,
    Group2 ASC
```